# Javascript "If" statement changes html image source

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm making a little point-and-click HTML game, while learning myself to code.

When I was testing stuff, I ran into a problem.
My javascript changes an image, which I did not expect it to do.

Somewhere in my code is this image.

`<img src="icon.jpg" id="img2">`

And somewhere else is this script.

```
 <script >
 if (document.getElementById('img2').src="images.jpg") {
 window.alert("hi");
 }
 else { window.alert("bye");}
    </script>
```

So, if the image source of img2 is images.jpg, you'll get an alert saying "hi", and if it's not images.jpg, you;ll get an alert saying "bye". Obviously, the source of that image is icon.jpg, which is not images.jpg, so I expected it to say "bye". But it doesn't do that. When refreshing or loading the page, the source of img2 is immediately changed to images.jpg and I get a "hi" alert.
How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: `document.getElementById('img2').src == "images.jpg")` -> you need to compare with _double_ equal sign : ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the equals a double equals.     
 `if (document.getElementById('img2').src=="images.jpg") {`

```js
function changeImg(){
  document.getElementById('img2').src="http://placebear.com/200/300";
  window.setTimeout(checkImg,1000);

}
  
  function checkImg(){
  if (document.getElementById('img2').src=="http://placebear.com/300/200") {
 window.alert("hi");
 }
 else { window.alert("bye");}
  }
checkImg();
```

```html
<img src="http://placebear.com/300/200" id="img2"/>
<button type="button" onclick="changeImg()">Click to change and run test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! :) Completely forgot about that. Also, that was a VERY quick response!

Comment: you're welcome. Don't think there's a single person on here that hasn't done exactly the same thing at some stage. Happy new year.

Comment: Another question because of this one. I've now this code `<img src="images.jpg" id="img2">` and this code `<area href="javascript:replaceImage('img2', 'icon.jpg', 'l2')" shape="rect" coords="100,350,150,400">`. Which means, originally there's an image with source images.jpg (alerting "hi"), which is changed by clicking to icon.jpg. After that change it won't alert me "bye". How can I make it alert "bye"?

Comment: can't see a change in the context of the question, should work, I'll do a code snippet to show it working. back in a mo.

Comment: Thank you very much. As I'm a new user I cannot upvote yet, but I would upvote your answer if I could :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your script as below:

```js
if ( document.getElementById('img2').getAttribute('src') == "images.jpg" ) {
  window.alert("hi");
  
}
else { 
 window.alert("bye");
}
```

```html
<img src="icon.jpg" id="img2">
```